# Two Select in android java giving exception

Tags: java, android

```js
String MY_QUERY = "select * from survey_tbl  WHERE " +
  "status = 'active' AND " +
  "mysql_sys_id = ?";
Cursor res = db.rawQuery(MY_QUERY, new String[] {
  String.valueOf(id)
});
res.moveToFirst();
//            finalmyArray = CreateJsonRecords(res);
while (res.isAfterLast() == false) {
  JSONObject k = new JSONObject();
  JSONObject l = new JSONObject();
  JSONObject m = new JSONObject();
  JSONObject n = new JSONObject();


  o.put("surveyid", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("sys_id")));
  o.put("surveynum", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("survey_num")));
  o.put("surveytitle", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("survey_title")));
  o.put("surveydescription", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("survey_description")));
  o.put("startdate", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("start_date")));
  o.put("enddate", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("end_date")));
  o.put("status", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("status")));

  res.moveToNext();


}
String MY_QUERY1 = "select *,t1.mysql_sys_id AS questionsysid from " +
  "question_tbl AS t1 LEFT JOIN " +
  "survey_tbl AS t2 ON t2.mysql_sys_id = t1.survey_id WHERE " +
  "t2.status = 'active' AND " +
  "t2.mysql_sys_id = ?";
Cursor res1 = db.rawQuery(MY_QUERY1, new String[] {
  String.valueOf(id)
});
System.out.println("res1 " + res1);
if (res1 != null && res1.moveToFirst()) {
  //            res1.moveToFirst();
  do {
    //            while (res1.isAfterLast() == false) {
    //question
    o.put("mysqlsysid", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("questionsysid")));
    o.put("questiondisplaynum", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("question_display_order")));
    o.put("questionorder", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("question_order")));
    o.put("questioncategory", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("question_category")));
    o.put("question", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("question")));
    o.put("status", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("status")));

    //                    res1.moveToNext();

  } while (res1.moveToNext());
  //            }
} else {
  System.out.println(res1);
}
```

I am using this query to select on two tables then adding both result into one JSON Object. This query is giving me

> android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 requested, with a size of 1

in line `o.put("mysqlsysid", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("questionsysid")));`

Question:

1. Why am getting this error.
2. How to solve this error.

Any idea is appreciated

`UPDATE`

TO make sure that the cursor is not empty I added

`System.out.println("getCount " + res1.getCount());` result is

> I/System.out: getCount 18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are reading the wrong cursor here I guess.

```
if (res1 != null && res1.moveToFirst()) {
  do {
    o.put("mysqlsysid", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("questionsysid")));
    o.put("questiondisplaynum", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("question_display_order")));
    o.put("questionorder", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("question_order")));
    o.put("questioncategory", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("question_category")));
    o.put("question", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("question")));
    o.put("status", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("status")));  
} while (res1.moveToNext());
```

Since you are looping on the cursor `res1` but your are reading `res`

So basicly you are trying to read the previous cursor but you have already reach the end with the first loop.

You should close your cursor to prevent this.

PS : You could use a while loop to remove the if
    while (res1 != null && res1.moveToFirst()){
        ...
    }

And I am not sure you need to check if the cursor exist (need to check the doc for that)

Comment: omg. i didnt see that one let me try i think it is the reason.

Comment: This is why cursor and query should be correctly named ;)

Answer (score -1):

You get data from cursor this way:
`Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(MY_QUERY, new String[] { String.valueOf(id)});
    try {
         while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
             // get data here
        }
    } finally {
         cursor.close;
    }`

Comment: if i dont move to first how will i get all the data in the cursor? are you sure about your answer?

Comment: @Giant, by default, a `Cursor`'s position is just before the beginning (in -1) so you can use a `while(c.moveToNext())` like this. So this is not incorrect, but not necessary an answer here.

Comment: I read your code again and relized you used cursor `res` instead of `res1`. You get data from `res` once, so its index is 1 now.